# Angular material datepicker doesn't work property with text-mask library

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using text-mask library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask) trying to use inside two angular datepicker component.
It's work when I need to set the date writring down into the input, but when I use the datepciker's icon, the date is not set into my reactive form.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off">
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Data Inicial</mat-label>
                <input matInput [textMask]="mask" [matDatepicker]="pickerInicial" formControlName="beginDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerInicial"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerInicial></mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>
    
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Data Final</mat-label>
                <input matInput [textMask]="mask" [matDatepicker]="pickerFinal" formControlName="endDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerFinal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerFinal></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[image]

TS

```
public mask = {
    guide: true,
    showMask: true,
    mask: [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/],
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.form = this._formBuilder?.group({
      beginDate: [],
      endDate: [],
    });
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to see how you set up your form and how you add it to your page?  I am trying to recreate it in stackblitz but the moment i add testMask it starts throwing this error:  More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I eddited it

Comment: did my below answer help at all? Sorry that I can't be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Oddly in stackblitz the moment i try to add the textMask it throws errors. However, there may be a way for you to tackle this. I suspect what you may need to do is tap into the `dateChange` event on the input property and manually set the value then.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Data Inicial</mat-label>
                <input matInput [textMask]="mask" [matDatepicker]="pickerInicial" formControlName="beginDate" (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerInicial"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerInicial></mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>

dateChanged(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
   let selectedDate = event.value;
   let formatted = formatDate(selectedDate, 'your format here', 'your culture, ex: en-US");

   this.form.controls["endDate"].setValue(formatted)

}
```

Something to this affect